# calling a jquery colorbox from a colorbox frame

Tags: jquery

hi all i use colorbox as my lightbox to display a div, frame or different page. one of the tables i display is on another page and would like to inistantiate another colorbox call from the same page which is already displaying on a colorbox....plz help

Comment: you may need to rephrase you question or provide some example code. It's a little difficult to follow exactly what you need as is.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include the Colorbox Javascript (alongside the jQuery javascript) and call the box as you would normally. Works for me.

However the Colorbox will appear UNDER the original colorbox.